# Panjer Distribution and $p_0<1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider a discrete random variable $X \geq 0 $. Then there are $a,b \in \mathbb{R}: a+b>0 $, such that $$p_k = \left(a+ \frac{b}{k}\right) p_{k-1} $$ with $p_k=P(X=k)$

How can I conclude that $p_0$ has to be less than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p_0\ge1$, then $p_0=1$ (since it’s a probability). Then $p_1=a+b\gt0$. But then $P(X=0\lor X=1)=1+p_1\gt1$, which can’t be (since it’s a probability).

Comment: Thank you very much:)